# Central cocharacter

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over a field $K$ and let $T$ be a maximal torus and let $B$ be a Borel subgroup containing $T$. Assume that $G$ is split over $K$ with respect to $T$. Let $\lambda$ be a dominant cocharacter. Is there a characterization of $\lambda$ being in the centre of $G$ in terms of dominant weights?

Comment: Are you interested in restricting this question to "charactrization in terms of *dominant* weights," or is a characterization in terms of root data sufficient? In any case, I'd point out that for any root $\alpha$, any cocharacter $\lambda$, and any $t \in K^{\times}, u \in K$, we have $\lambda(t) x_{\alpha}(u) = x_{\alpha}(u) \lambda(t)$ iff $\langle \alpha, \lambda \rangle = 0$

Comment: @Jackson Thanks! That makes a lot of sense now. Is there a characterization of it in terms of dominant weights? Also, is it always true that half sum of positive roots equal sum of fundamental weights or is it true only for semisimple groups?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what it would mean to have a condition in terms of dominant weights, but I did find a necessary (not sufficient) condition: a cocharacter in the center of $G$ must be the vertex of a dominant cone in $X_*(T)$.
As far as the half sum of positive roots, my understanding is that a non-semisimple group will have the same fundamental weights as a semisimple group of the same type (as well as the same positive roots), so the answer shouldn't change. But I'm not totally sure I have the right definition of fundamental weight in the non-semisimple case

Comment: @Jackson Thanks for your help!